# function to get the file name of an URL

Tags: iphone

I have some source code to get the file name of an url

for example:

http://www.google.com/a.pdf

I hope to get a.pdf

because the way to join 2 NSStrings I can get is 'appendString' which only for adding a string at right side, so I planned to check each char one by one from the right side of string 'http://www.google.com/a.pdf', when it reach at the char '/', stop the checking, return string fdp.a , after that I change fdp.a to a.pdf

source codes are below

```
-(NSMutableString *) getSubStringAfterH :  originalString:(NSString *)s0 
{
    NSInteger i,l;
    l=[s0 length];
    NSMutableString *h=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    NSMutableString *ttt=[[NSMutableString alloc] init  ];
     for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--) //check each char one by one from the right side of string 'http://www.google.com/a.pdf', when it reach at the char '/', stop
    {
        ttt=[s0 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
         if([ttt isEqualToString:@"/"]) 
        { 
            break;
        }
            else
        {
             [h appendString:ttt];
        } 
     }
     [ttt release];
     NSMutableString *h1=[[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@""] autorelease];

    for (i=[h length]-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
            NSMutableString *t1=[[NSMutableString alloc] init ];
        t1=[h substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
        [h1 appendString:t1];
            [t1 release];
    } 
    [h release];
    return h1;
}
```

h1 can reuturn the coorect string a.pdf, but if it returns to the codes where it was called, after a while system reports
'double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug'

I checked a long time and foudn that if I removed the code

ttt=[s0 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];

everything will be Ok (of course getSubStringAfterH can not returns the corrent result I expected.), no error reported.

I try to fix the bug a few hours, but still no clue.

Welcome any comment

Thanks 
interdev

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try this:

**Edit**: from blow comment

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.google.com/a.pdf";
NSArray *parts = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *filename = [parts lastObject];
```

Comment: NSString *filename = [parts lastObject];

Comment: If you must go with splitting the path into parts, at least use pathComponents rather than componentsSeparatedByString.  But one of the other methods below would be better anyway.

Comment: I think It's not a good idea to use the last path components, what about different URLs with the same last path components ?

Answer (score 177):

The following line does the job if url is a NSString:

```
NSString *filename = [url lastPathComponent];
```

If url is a NSURL, then the following does the job:

```
NSString *filename = [[url path] lastPathComponent];
```

Comment: Minor issue with this is that given @"http://www.google.com/" (slash at end), it returns @"www.google.com" which may not be what you want.

Comment: Um, another minor issue: "Note that this method only works with file paths (not, for example, string representations of URLs)." from the docs http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/lastPathComponent

Comment: An alternative that seems to work for both file system and network URLs is [[myNSURL pathComponents] lastObject];.  If you want to make sure it's a real file, you could check the [myNSURL pathExtension].

Comment: or even just [url lastPathComponent]; since ios 4.0

Comment: +10 because [url path] gives me a more attractive name than [url description]

Answer (score 10):

I think if you have already had the `NSURL` object, there is `lastPathComponent` method available from the iOS 4 onwards.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/a.pdf"];
NSString *filename = [url lastPathComponent];
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3**

Let's say that your url is http://www.google.com/a.pdf

```
    let filename = url.lastPathComponent

    \\filename = "a.pdf"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is more error free and meant for getting the localized name in the URL.

```
NSString *localizedName = nil;
[url getResourceValue:&localizedName forKey:NSURLLocalizedNameKey error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this yet, but it seems like you might be trying to do this the hard way.  The iPhone libraries have the `NSURL` class, and I imagine that you could simply do:

```
NSString *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/a.pdf"];
NSString *path = [url path];
```

Definitely look for a built in function.  The libraries have far more testing and will handle the edge cases better than anything you or I will write in an hour or two (generally speaking).

Comment: Thanks

But it returns file name with path rather than filename
for example

/download/10925221/11263992/1/mp4/39/71/1268527574311_583/03002001004B9B86E1927C01CCF99112E21A1F-E815-DA28-CB74-4CA536C67D87.mp4

rather than 03002001004B9B86E1927C01CCF99112E21A1F-E815-DA28-CB74-4CA536C67D87.mp4