# Objective c Substring

Tags: objective-c

Please help me, I want to Substring like that " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/abc.pdf "
and I want to get " **abc.pdf** ". It mean I want to get file name of pdf.

Note: it is not the same string.
 Forexample : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/abc.pdf,
              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/tosf/abc.pdf and sometime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/tosf/12/abc.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [function to get the file name of an URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440620/function-to-get-the-file-name-of-an-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `lastPathComponent` method of NSURL.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/abc.pdf"];
NSString *filename = [url lastPathComponent];
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Rijo answer. No need to create `NSURL` instance, you can use `lastPathComponent` method of `NSString`:

```
NSString *filename = [@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/abc.pdf" lastPathComponent];
```